# add a reference to other dll's when my own dll is added to a project

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, dll

I have built a class library that will require other dlls from a third party to be present on the end user's machine.  I only ever envisage this tool being used by existing users of the third party as it simply adds some missing functionality.

In order to make it as simple as possible for the end user is it possible to have my dll add references to the other dlls when it itself is added as a reference in a project (if it finds the required third party dll's to be absent from the project) and if so how do one do this?  I know exactly where the third party dlls will be located on an end user's machine.

Finally I have been struggling to find the correct term for this type of operation in order to do more searching myself.  If there is a specific term for this could you let me know what it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your intent is load a dll at runtime :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(@"YOUR_FILE_PATH\DLL.dll");

Type type = assembly.GetType("MyType");

object instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```